# Create a payment method in stripe

Tags: java, spring-boot, stripe-payments, payment-method

I wish to create a payment method in stripe and attach it to a existing customer using java -spring boot.
The  [stripe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/create?shell=true&api=true&resource=payment_methods&action=create)

shares an example code for creating a payment method using a card.
The code is

```
PaymentMethodCreateParams params =
  PaymentMethodCreateParams.builder()
    .setType(PaymentMethodCreateParams.Type.CARD)
    .setCard(
      PaymentMethodCreateParams.Card.builder()
        .setNumber("4242424242424242")
        .setExpMonth(8L)
        .setExpYear(2026L)
        .setCvc("314")
        .build()
    )
    .build();
PaymentMethod paymentMethod = PaymentMethod.create(params);
```

But upon running this code, we get response

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Sending credit card numbers directly to the Stripe API is generally unsafe. We suggest you use test tokens that map to the test card you are using, see https://stripe.com/docs/testing. To enable raw card data APIs in test mode, see https://support.stripe.com/questions/enabling-access-to-raw-card-data-apis.",
    "request_log_url": "https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/req_9c6QitRqUgqM1i?t=1699942446",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```

Upon reading further i understood that **we need to accept card details in front-end using stripe.js and get a card token which we will pass to server side**.

**My Question here is that after getting the token from client how do i create a payment method out of it and attach it to an existing customer.**
Any help in this direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As part of PCI compliance, your system is only allowed to pass raw card details if you complete [SAQ-D](https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide#validating-pci-compliance). If you don't, I'd recommend using stripe.js to collect the payment method details using Payment Element with the guide [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse?platform=web&ui=elements). Setup Intent flow will create a payment method and attach to an existing customer.

Comment: thanks. But do you meant that first collect the payment method details using Payment Element from front end and then in the server side create setup intent flow.
OR both are separate paths.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My Question here is that after getting the token from client how do i create a payment method out of it and attach it to an existing customer.

I don't really understand the question, the token and the payment method aren't different objects here really, but I understand the confusion.

It's worth mentioning that Stripe does have a function you can call on the frontend to [create a Payment Method](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_methods/create_payment_method).
Now, if I recall correctly, you still can't hardcode the card details with it, it will ask you to use Elements instead, but it's not really relevant because this function is really not used beyond very specific [use-cases](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/build-a-two-step-confirmation#create-pm).

The reason why is that collecting a payment method isn't just about collecting the card details, you also need to perform additional steps (i.e. authentication) to authorize your application to charge the saved card later. This is something that this function doesn't do, hence why it shouldn't be used unless you have some logic to perform these actions later.

If you want to collect payment methods for future use and the above documentation isn't relevant, then you have two options:
-Save the payment method without a payment - using a [Setup Intent](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse).
This would automatically create a payment method for you when it's successfully confirmed. If you add a `customer` to it, it would automatically attach it to them as well.

-Save the payment method with a payment - using a [Payment Intent](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-during-payment).
Same logic applies here, except there's a charge in the flow as well.

These are the methods you should use, rather than creating Payment Methods, as they'll automatically perform any additional steps required to allow you to use the payment method later.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This was helpful. but I still have questions. Going through the Setup Intent docs, what I understood was, create checkout session--> retrieve session -->retrieve setup intent  --> retrieve payment method.    now you can attach this payment method with existing customer or might choose to create session providing customer id in the beginning itself.

But I didn't find any place where Card Details or any such information is being taken.. I mean payment method is generated but there is no information recorded about how payment will be done...

Comment: The Stripe Checkout integration is a Stripe-hosted page you redirect the customer to, where they complete the form and save their card.
If you're using Elements, you would load the payment method fields yourself on your page: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse?platform=web&ui=elements Regarding the payment you're mentioning, charging the card later is documented here, as it's not intended to be performed with Stripe Checkout (though you could, it just defeats the purpose): https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse?platform=web&ui=elements#charge-saved-payment-method